# Should I use tf or tf2 for broadcasting/receiving transforms?

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, ros-hydro, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As highlighted here:

https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/20

http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/tf2/Migration

There are some issues with using tf2 as opposed to tf.  As someone who is just now looking into using these features, what should I be looking at?  Are tf2 and its tutorials something which should be avoided at the moment? Will the documentation/package for tf2 be fixed any time soon?  I'm looking into writing a simple broadcaster/receiver for my Kinect transforms in Rviz and would really like some guidance and what tutorials to look at.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131176/should-i-use-tf-or-tf2-for-broadcasting/receiving-transforms?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf2 follows similar design patterns. The API documentation is fine. However the tutorials are out of date due to a renamespacing of certain functionality for API review.

If you want a quick tutorial and to get going quickly tf is probably your best bet.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2